# How to display child-category PAGES on a category page

Tags: categories

On a category page ( www.mdrnfashion.com/nba-players/ ) I would like to display on the child category PAGES ( www.mdrnfashion.com/nba-players/lebron-james/ ), and **not** the child category's POSTS.

This image shows a good overview of the hierarchy I am trying to achieve. [image]

Here is my category.php

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $cb_cats = get_the_category();
    $cb_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $cb_blog_style = cb_get_blog_style();
    $cb_cat_title_bg = $cb_tax_id = $cb_taxonomy = $cb_tax_qry = NULL; 
    $cb_archive_title_bg_src = cb_archive_title_bg();

    if ( function_exists('get_tax_meta') ) {

        $cb_category_color_style = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_style_color');
        $cb_featured_option = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_featured_op');
        $cb_category_ad = get_tax_meta_strip($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_ad');
        $cb_category_color = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_color_field_id');
        if ( ($cb_category_color == '#' ) || ( $cb_category_color == NULL ) ) {

            $cb_parent_cat_id = $cb_cats[0]->parent;
            if ($cb_parent_cat_id != '0') {
                $cb_category_color = get_tax_meta($cb_parent_cat_id, 'cb_color_field_id');
            }
        }

    } else {
        $cb_category_color = $cb_category_ad = NULL;
        $cb_featured_option = 'Off';
    }

    if ( ($cb_category_color == NULL) || ($cb_category_color == '#')) {
         $cb_category_color = ot_get_option('cb_base_color', '#eb9812');
    }

    if ( isset( $cb_archive_title_bg_src[1] )  ) {
        $cb_cat_title_bg =  'data-cb-bg="' . $cb_archive_title_bg_src[1] . '"';
    }
?>

<div id="cb-content" class="wrap clearfix">

<div id="cb-cat-header" class="cb-cat-header cb-section-header" style="border-bottom-color:<?php echo $cb_category_color; ?>;" <?php echo $cb_cat_title_bg; ?>>
    <h1 id="cb-cat-title"><?php echo get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name; ?></h1>
    <?php echo category_description( $cb_cat_id ); ?>
</div>

<?php 
if ( ( $cb_featured_option != 'Off' ) && ( $cb_featured_option != NULL ) && ( $cb_featured_option != 'slider' )  && ( $cb_featured_option != 's-1' ) ) {

    $cb_flipped = NULL;
    $j = 0;
    $cb_section = 'a';
    include( locate_template( 'library/modules/cb-'.$cb_featured_option.'.php' ) );

}

echo cb_breadcrumbs();

if ( ( $cb_featured_option != 'Off' ) && ( $cb_featured_option != NULL ) && ( $cb_featured_option == 's-1' ) ) {

    $cb_flipped = NULL;
    $j = 0;
    $cb_section = 'a';
    include( locate_template( 'library/modules/cb-' . $cb_featured_option . '.php' ) );

}  
?>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="main" class="cb-main clearfix cb-module-block cb-blog-style-roll">

        <?php

            if ( $cb_category_ad != NULL ) {
                echo '<div class="cb-category-top">' . do_shortcode( $cb_category_ad ) . '</div>';
            }

            if ( $cb_featured_option == 'slider' ) {
                $cb_section = $cb_title = $cb_module_style = $j = NULL;
                include( locate_template( 'library/modules/cb-s-2.php' ) );
            }

            include( locate_template( 'cat-' . $cb_blog_style . '.php') );

        ?>

    </div> <!-- /main -->

    <?php if ( $cb_blog_style != 'style-c' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>
    </div>

</div> <!-- end /#cb-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and here is an example of a category style

```
    <?php /* Category/Blog Style A */

$cb_qry = cb_get_qry();

if ( $cb_qry->have_posts() ) : while ( $cb_qry->have_posts() ) : $cb_qry->the_post();
global $post;
$cb_post_id = $post->ID;
$cb_category_color = cb_get_cat_color( $cb_post_id );
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('cb-blog-style-a cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix' ); ?> role="article">

<div class="cb-mask" style="background-color:<?php echo $cb_category_color; ?>;">

<?php
    cb_thumbnail('360', '240');
    echo cb_review_ext_box( $cb_post_id, $cb_category_color );
?>

</div>

<div class="cb-meta">

  <h2 class="cb-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php echo cb_byline(); ?>
  <div class="cb-excerpt"><?php echo cb_clean_excerpt( 210, false ); ?></div>

</div>

</article>

<?php

endwhile;
cb_page_navi( $cb_qry );
endif;
 wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $cb_cats = get_the_category();
    $cb_cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    $cb_blog_style = cb_get_blog_style();

    $cb_cat_title_bg = $cb_tax_id = $cb_taxonomy = $cb_tax_qry = NULL; 
    $cb_archive_title_bg_src = cb_archive_title_bg();

    if ( function_exists('get_tax_meta') ) {

        $cb_category_color_style = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_style_color');
        $cb_featured_option = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_featured_op');
        $cb_category_ad = get_tax_meta_strip($cb_cat_id, 'cb_cat_ad');
        $cb_category_color = get_tax_meta($cb_cat_id, 'cb_color_field_id');
        if ( ($cb_category_color == '#' ) || ( $cb_category_color == NULL ) ) {

            $cb_parent_cat_id = $cb_cats[0]->parent;
            if ($cb_parent_cat_id != '0') {
                $cb_category_color = get_tax_meta($cb_parent_cat_id, 'cb_color_field_id');
            }
        }

    } else {
        $cb_category_color = $cb_category_ad = NULL;
        $cb_featured_option = 'Off';
    }

    if ( ($cb_category_color == NULL) || ($cb_category_color == '#')) {
         $cb_category_color = ot_get_option('cb_base_color', '#eb9812');
    }

    if ( isset( $cb_archive_title_bg_src[1] )  ) {
        $cb_cat_title_bg =  'data-cb-bg="' . $cb_archive_title_bg_src[1] . '"';
    }
?>

<div id="cb-content" class="wrap clearfix">

<div id="cb-cat-header" class="cb-cat-header cb-section-header"    style="border-bottom-color:<?php echo $cb_category_color; ?>;" <?php echo $cb_cat_title_bg; ?>>
        <h1 id="cb-cat-title"><?php echo get_category(get_query_var('cat'))-             >name; ?></h1>
    <?php echo category_description( $cb_cat_id ); ?>
</div>
```

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="main" class="cb-main clearfix cb-module-block cb-blog-style-roll">

        <?php

            $term = get_queried_object();
            $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
                'parent'    => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => true
                ) );

            $cb_count = 1;
            $cb_counter = 1;

            if($children) {

                foreach($children as $child){

                    if ( ( $cb_blog_style == 'style-b' || $cb_blog_style == 'style-e' ) && $cb_count == 3 ) { $cb_count = 1; }
                    if ( $cb_blog_style == 'style-c' && $cb_count == 4 ) { $cb_count = 1; }
                    if ( $cb_blog_style == 'style-g' && $cb_counter == 4 ) { $cb_counter = 1; }

                    if($cb_blog_style == 'style-a'){ $image_size = 'cb-360-240'; $post_class = 'cb-blog-style-a cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix'; }
                    if($cb_blog_style == 'style-b'){ $image_size = 'cb-360-240'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-b cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-article-row-2 cb-article-row cb-separated clearfix cb-no-$cb_count";}
                    if($cb_blog_style == 'style-c'){ $image_size = 'cb-360-240'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-c cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-article-row-3 cb-article-row cb-separated clearfix cb-no-$cb_count";}
                    if($cb_blog_style == 'style-d'){ $image_size = 'cb-750-400'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-d cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix";}
                    if($cb_blog_style == 'style-e'){ $image_size = 'cb-300-250'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-e cb-small cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-article-row-2 cb-article-row cb-separated clearfix cb-no-$cb_count";}
                    if($cb_counter % 3  == 0 && $cb_blog_style == 'style-f'){ $image_size = 'cb-750-400'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-d cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix";}
                    if($cb_counter % 3  != 0 && $cb_blog_style == 'style-f'){ $image_size = 'cb-360-240'; $post_class = 'cb-blog-style-a cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix';}
                    if($cb_counter % 3  == 0 && $cb_blog_style == 'style-g'){ $image_size = 'cb-750-400'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-d cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-separated clearfix";}
                    if($cb_counter % 3  != 0 && $cb_blog_style == 'style-g'){ $image_size = 'cb-360-240'; $post_class = "cb-blog-style-b cb-blog-style cb-color-hover cb-article-row-2 cb-article-row cb-separated clearfix cb-no-$cb_counter";}


                    ?>


                    <article <?php post_class( $post_class ); ?> >
                        <div class="cb-mask" style="background-color:<?php echo $cb_category_color; ?>;">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id); ?>">
                                <?php z_taxonomy_image($child->term_id, $image_size ); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cb-meta">
                            <h2 class="cb-post-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $child->name; ?>
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                            <?php if ($cb_blog_style != 'style-e') { ?> <div class="cb-excerpt"><?php echo $child->description; ?></div> <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </article>



                    <?php

                    $cb_count++;
                    $cb_counter++;
                    }

            }
            else {

                if ( $cb_category_ad != NULL ) {
                    echo '<div class="cb-category-top">' . do_shortcode( $cb_category_ad ) . '</div>';
                }

                if ( $cb_featured_option == 'slider' ) {
                    $cb_section = $cb_title = $cb_module_style = $j = NULL;
                    include( locate_template( 'library/modules/cb-s-2.php' ) );
                }

                include( locate_template( 'cat-' . $cb_blog_style . '.php') );

            }

        ?>

    </div> <!-- /main -->

    <?php if ( $cb_blog_style != 'style-c' ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: that is the solution